# Phaser 3 Video lagging on "old" iOS

Tags: javascript, video, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I'm relatively new to Phaser 3 and I wanted to add a video and play it automatically.
While it plays well on my desktop using Chrome or Safari, on devices like iPhone 6 running iOS 12 or an iPhone X running iOS 14.5 it is almost not playing at all, a few frames and then the frames are not updating.
It is displaying without issue on an iPhone 11 Pro running iOS 16.6.

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.70.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene
    {
        preload ()
        {
            this.load.video('preview', 'preview.mp4');
        }

        create ()
        {
            let video = this.add.video(0,0, 'preview');
            video.setOrigin(0,0);
            video.setMute(true);
            video.play();
        }
    };

    const config = {
        type: Phaser.WEBGL,
        scene: [TestScene],
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    };
    const game = new Phaser.Game (config);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a setting or something making lagging like this? It is like the rendering doesn't follow the video.

Comment: If it shows some frames and stops working that sound like a issue with the browser/OS/phone, since phaser just uses standard HTML elements and components. You could post you question in the phaser discord channel or the [discourse forum](https://phaser.discourse.group/), since there are phaser developers there, that might have encountered this issue.

Comment: Thanks I posted on the forum too and post any update here. I tried to display a video in the html page using the <video> tag and it works well, so I don’t know what is the difference with Phaser way to display. Conflict with the webgl renderer maybe

Comment: No one had a solution, but I discovered that using `type: Phaser.CANVAS` worked without problem, for my needs CANVAS is not a big deal. Definitely an issue with the WEGL renderer with video.

Comment: That is a bit disappointing, but thank you for sharing your results.